# zero values instead of negative values in data grid view

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get rid of having negative values on the datagrid and I only want to show that once the item goes out of stock it will only show zero instead of -4

things to consider:
- I call my datagridview manually here:

```
void GetInventory()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = @"SELECT * FROM InventoryTable";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                dgvItem.DataSource = dt;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you have any specific columns for those you want this ?

Comment: It's better to fix the problem at its source. Why are the values negative in the first place (considering that they're stock values)? Do you actually need them to be negative in the database?

Comment: my specific column in the database is quantity

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed no, I need to at least show it to be zero values instead, I've used int as the Quantity's data type in the database

Comment: Good, if you don't want to have negative quantities in the DB, then ask yourself this: **"What causes them to be negative in the first place?"** and try to fix that. If you couldn't figure it out, ask a question _about that_.

Comment: `select case when quantity < 0 then 0 else quantity end as quantity, * from InventoryTable` could also do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be handled in the sql query.
This is responsibility of the view logic. DataGridView is view's control and could be right place to convert quantity into "friendly" value.

`DataGridView.CelLFormatting` event handler could be right tool for the job.

```
// In constructor
dgvItem.CellFormatting += dgvItem_CellFormatting;


private void dgvItem_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "Quantity")
    {
        return;
    }

    if (e.Value == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var quantity = (decimal)e.Value;
    if (quantity < 0)
    {
        e.Value = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void ReplaceAllNegativeWithZeros(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value != null)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value.ToString()) < 0)
                    {
                        cell.Value = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `N0` doesn't replace negative values with a zero.

Comment: wait where did you edit it? at least let me try it first

Comment: oh wait, I can't try it since I call my datagrid view manually with a code, what I only need to do is to atleast show my quantity as zero whenever is runs out of stock instead of having negative value

Comment: @JonathanSumilang I did not change the content of the answer :) I simply made the screenshot appear in it rather than displaying a link. Hint: you can always review the edit history of any post by clicking on [edited](https://i.postimg.cc/kG78K5fh/edited.png).

Comment: how can I comment my screenshot? im sorry im only new here

Comment: public static void ReplaceAllNegativeWithZeros(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(cell.Value.ToString()) < 0)
                        {
                            cell.Value = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

So you are having products that have minus stock but you do not want final user too see it but just to see 0 (which means out of stock).

There are many approach to this problem but let's say you cannot avoid getting into minus then you can filter your datagridview after populating it. Additional function = slower program so reconsider solving problem with not getting into minus.

So how it could be done is with `extension`.

You create it like this (i will put simple example):

```
public static void ReplaceAllNegativeWithZeros(this DataGridView dgv)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in dgv.Cells)
        {
            //This will loop through all cells in your currently displayed datagridview
            //You call this function like yourDataGridViewInForm.ReplaceAllNegativeWithZeros();

            //Here check if value from cell meets your condition and then change it.
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can check all your cells (or just one column) and do with it's values whatever you need (replace them to 0 if < 0)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have your query return a formatted or calculated value, like this for example

```
select case when i.quantity < 0 then 0 else i.quantity end as quantityZero, 
       i.* 
from InventoryTable i
```

Now you can put the original `quantity` column invisible on your datagridview.
This way you have both the original value at hand should you need it, and a value that will show `zero` when `< 0` to display

It is also best practice to not do `select *` but to always list the fields you need.